# Django email backend with local smtp

Tags: django, smtp, django-mailer

I want send email from django application.

I want send an email to my mail id from other username without authentication. Just i used smtp server for the authenticated mail.In the django mail api How it is supposed to send an mail with the local smtp?

Comment: Try https://github.com/kennethreitz/inbox.py

Answer (score 12):

As stated on the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs you need to:

- On your `settings.py` define the following:

  EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
  EMAIL_PORT = 1025
- Then, in another shell run the following command:

  python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025

That will run a dummy SMTP server, that actually will not send any email but you'll be able to see the output and check if that's correct. If you want to *actually* send your emails during development, you will need to install a SMTP server like sendmail and use that in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be a simple and easy solution for development environment. This will just print the email on the console:

Set the following variable in your environment

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
```